# PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues does not work for custom Preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences, default-value

I'm working on a little app with a lot of modifiable preferences, most of them being `SeekBarPreferences`.

It happens that, since I'm quite not happy with Android default `SeekBarPreferences`, I'm using the very good [MaterialSeekBarPreference](https://github.com/MrBIMC/MaterialSeekBarPreference) library which unfortunately have not been updated for 2 years.

Here is an example of code used by this library:

```
<com.pavelsikun.seekbarpreference.SeekBarPreference
    android:key="@string/param_maxEvent"
    android:title="Blahlblahblahblahblah"
    android:summary="Blahlblahblahblahblah too"
    android:defaultValue="2"
    custom:msbp_minValue="0"
    custom:msbp_maxValue="5"
    custom:msbp_measurementUnit="events"
    custom:msbp_interval="1"
    custom:msbp_dialogEnabled="false"/>
```

As you can see, you can use the `android:defaultValue` xml attribute, and it works perfectly with the UI.

Since I need to load all these default values at app initialization, I use the `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues` method:

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true);
    }
}
```

This works fine with all default preferences (`SwitchPreference`, `ListPreference`, `Preference`), but unfortunately not with these custom `SeekBarPreference`.

Loading the preferences activity does not set up thoses default values either.

Is there any workaround for this problem ? Else, if I was up to edit the library, what should I change ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the method `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this, R.xml.preferences, true);`. Instead, I use `preference.setDefaultValue(object);` in the Fragment.